# Select dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I can't be able to select values from the dropdown in selenium webdriver. I tried all the ways using name and xpath selectors. Please help.

The code is:

```
<span id="cboEmploymentTypeId" class="select" tabindex="0" name="cboEmploymentTypeId" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none; box-shadow: none;">
```

Comment: Is your listbox is associated with <option> or <li>??? Check below video may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfYj3DYnN0c

Comment: Yes associated with <option>

Comment: Then watch the video, it will help.

Comment: <label for="cboEmploymentTypeId">
<select id="cboEmploymentTypeId" onchange="Custom.showAdditionalFields(this);" name="cboEmploymentTypeId" style="display: none;">
<option class="" value="">-- Välj jobbtyp --</option>
<option class="opt1" value="1">Fast anställd</option>
<option class="opt2" value="2">Egen företagare</option>
...
</select>
<span id="cboEmploymentTypeId" class="select" tabindex="0" 

<span data-value="">-- Välj jobbtyp --</span>
<span data-value="1">Fast anställd</span>
<span data-value="2">Egen företagare</span>
.....

Comment: The code is shown in above

Comment: new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("cboEmploymentTypeId"))).selectByVisibleText("Fast anställd"); But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@browser.select_list(name:"cboEmploymentTypeId").option[1...n].select
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your answer! Could you please edit it to add a little more information to your answer - because this is a very old question, anyone finding it from a search engine may appreciate a little more context.